# How to extract audio with youtube-dl on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, ffprobe, youtube-dl

I want to extract audio from a video downloaded with youtube-dl on Windows. I got youtube-dl working, but am unable to extract the audio. This problem is caused due to not having the correct audio codes installed.

When I try to extract audio it tells me the following:

```
WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codes with ffprobe
```

The youtube-dl manual says:

```
-x -extract-audio    convert video files to audio-only files (requires ffmpeg or avconv and ffprobe or avprobe)
```

How do I install ffprobe or ffmpeg? Do I install this on Windows, or do I install this as a Python extension?

My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ffmpeg` is not a Python module. Take a look at the code of `youtube-dl` in the `FFmpegExtractAudioPP` class.

It uses this call to figure out if the executable exists or not. It checks in your current path:

```
subprocess.Popen([exe, '-version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

You'll need to download the [Windows builds of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and put them in your current path, probably making sure that they do not have `.exe` at the end of their names.

Comment: Thanks for the response, would you be so kind to help me out a little more detailed, it would save me a lot of time. Which files do i need to download exactly and what do I do with them? Do I need to remove the exe? Do I need to change the python code? I have never written python before so i wouldn't know how :S

Comment: @user1160265 I think your question is better suited to SuperUser if it isn't a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; it really helped me. I don't think having `.exe` as the extension of the ffmpeg binaries matters, though. I just extracted the ffmpeg build to `C:` and added its `bin` directory to my PATH, and ytdl worked fine. (I'd edit your answer, but I'm not confident enough to generalize to everybody)

Answer (score 7):

A quick fix for Windows users:

1. Download the ffmpeg package from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, unzip it, copy ALL the contents of the Bin directory to the directory where youtube-dl.exe is located.
2. Using DOS navigate to the directory where youtube-dl is located and run using the command:

   ```
   youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I've searched for this for quite a while. I've searched around the internet and some people say to put it inside a 'bin' folder in the installation folder or `FFmpeg/bin` or use the --FFmpeg-location. Nothing helped besides bluntly putting the executables in the youtubedl folder.

Comment: That site no longer exists

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

Future users may want to download the latest build from [ffmpeg.org](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

---

*My rep doesn't allow me to add a comment so I will put in here.*

As per Sep 18, 2020 http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ is closed, but still accessible via Web Archive. The complete downloads are still available from here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20200918193047/https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

I have made the following files/versions available for Windows users from my Google Drive but please don't take these as granted, and scan for malware or viruses as always:

```
ffmpeg-4.2.2-win32-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.2.2-win64-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.2.3-win32-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.2.3-win64-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.3-win32-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.3-win64-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.3.1-win32-static.zip
ffmpeg-4.3.1-win64-static.zip
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oj3VndOC-bGhfpNcHW3otIR--V2wxdG-?usp=sharing

Once downloaded, I extracted the latest build (4.3.1) on Windows 10 and copied all the .exe (`ffmpeg`, `ffplay`, `ffprobe`) to the same directory as `youtube-dl`, and then run:

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get win-ffmpeg using [chocolatey](http://www.chocolatey.org)

and if you still can’t get youtube-dl and ffmpeg to work together,

maybe you can do it in two steps:

1. Get mp4 or avi : youtube-dl url
2. Extract audio

   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -codec copy out.mp3

Answer (score 0):

I use packages available on conda-forge to accomplish this on Windows. The `yt-dlp` script should be in your `%PATH%` after installation in a conda environment. *Note:* I tested this with Git Bash, not Windows Terminal/Powershell

```
(yt-dlp) $ conda install ffmpeg yt-dlp
(yt-dlp) $ yt-dlp --version
(yt-dlp) $ ffmpeg --version
(yt-dlp) $ yt-dlp --extract-audio --audio-format wav https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc
```

You can also do this with Python code. Most of the Python code below was taken from [yt-dlp documentation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#usage-and-options).

```py
import yt_dlp


URLS = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc']


# https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#extract-audio
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'm4a/bestaudio/best',
    # See help(yt_dlp.postprocessor) for a list of available
    # Postprocessors and their arguments
    'postprocessors': [{  # Extract audio using ffmpeg
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'wav'
    }]
}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    error_code = ydl.download(URLS)
```